# How to create a modal bottom sheet which opens from the right side and only shows 80% of it's width

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Here's how it should look like

[Bottom sheet from the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quyQD.png)

it can be opened by clicking the icon

[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljCeO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the build in `Drawer` widget.

```dart
Scaffold(
  endDrawer: Drawer(
    child: ...
  ),
),
```

Click [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer#interactive-example) for more information from Flutter.